# Getting ERROR: type "period" does not exist, even i have added btree_gist and temporal_tables extensions

Tags: postgresql, temporal-tables, btree-gist

I'm getting error even i have added `btree_gist` and `temporal_tables` extensions.

```
postgres=# \dx

      Name       | Version |   Schema   |                  Description                  
-----------------+---------+------------+-----------------------------------------------
 btree_gist      | 1.1     | public     | support for indexing common datatypes in GiST
 plpgsql         | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
 temporal_tables | 1.2.0   | public     | temporal tables
```

(3 rows)

```
CREATE TABLE b (p PERIOD);
ERROR:  type "period" does not exist
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE b (p PERIOD);
```

### Version details

```
postgres=# select version();
                                           version                                           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.5.12 on x86_64-alpine-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 5.3.0) 5.3.0, 64-bit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about [this extension](https://github.com/arkhipov/temporal_tables/), I am not surprised.

The extension does not define a data type or domain called `period`.

Comment: Yes, i'm talking about that extension only. I was following this link http://thoughts.davisjeff.com/2010/09/25/exclusion-constraints-are-generalized-sql-unique/. But it is not working.

Comment: That page says that you have to install an extension [temporal](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/temporal) to get the data type `period`.

Comment: Then you probably have to qualify `period` with the name of the schema where you installed the extension (check `\dx`). Or you lack permissions on that schema. Can you see the data type in `\dx+ temporal`?

Comment: postgres=# \dx+ temporal_tables;
       Objects in extension "temporal_tables"
                 Object Description                 
----------------------------------------------------
 function set_system_time(timestamp with time zone)
 function versioning()
(2 rows)

Comment: No, not `temporal_tables`, but `temporal`. You got the wrong extension.

Comment: Oh No, let me check then. Thank you @Laurenz